# What is wrong with my iconButton in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui, icons

The console announce mistake at my *IconButton* open tag as *unexpected token*. i have installed material ui...i don't know what is the problem? can anyone help me? Thank you so much!

This is my product.js:

```
 import React from 'react'
import {
    Card,
    CardMedia,
    CardContent,
    CardActions,
    Typography,
    IconButton
} from '@material-ui/core'
import {
    AddShoppingCart
} from '@material-ui/icons'

import useStyles from './styles'

const Product = ({
    product
}) => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return ( 
    <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardMedia className={classes.media} image='' title={product.name} />
        <CardContent>
          <div className={classes.cardContent}>
            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" >
              {product.name}
            </Typography>
            <Typography  variant="h5" >
              {product.price}
            </Typography>
          </div>
          
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
          <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
            <AddShoppingCart />
          </IconButton>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    )
}

export default Product
```

This is my styles.js:

```
import {
    makeStyles
} from '@material-ui/core/styles'

export default makeStyles(() => ({
    {
        root: {
            maxWidth: '100%'
        },
        media: {
            height: 0,
            paddingTop: '56.25%'
        },
        cardActions: {
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-between'
        },

    }
}))
```

Btw i don't get where *useStyles* in my product.js come from when in my styles.js it's *makeStyles* not *useStyles* (i follow a tutorial on yt and he does so)

Comment: Please show detail error

Comment: it's just at my IconButton open tag that the console announce mistake as "unexpected token"

Answer (score 0):

This: `import useStyles from './styles'` is named that because you/him wanted to, because you're exporting `export default makeStyles`.

`export default` means that you can import it with any name you want, its not a named export.

The problem maybe because here:

```
// You're returning an object of an object, instead of the inner { root: ... }.
({
    {
        root: {
            maxWidth: '100%'
        },
        media: {
            height: 0,
            paddingTop: '56.25%'
        },
        cardActions: {
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-between'
        },

    }
}))
```

so maybe classes is not defined correctly, it would be needed the error stack to make sure where the error is, or at least a simple jsfiddle with the error would do.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your IconButton component.

Some hints:

1. You can import your styles as classes right away, otherwise I doubt the class definitions will work at all.
2. Ensure you have installed `@material-ui/icons`

I took your code and did above changes:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardMedia,
  CardContent,
  CardActions,
  Typography,
  IconButton
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { AddShoppingCart } from "@material-ui/icons";

import classes from "./styles";

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardMedia className={classes.media} image="/" title={product.name} />
      <CardContent>
        <div className={classes.cardContent}>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {product.name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            {product.price}
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
        <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
          <AddShoppingCart />
        </IconButton>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-sea-m9k33?file=/src/Product.js

Answer (score 0):

we have used an arrow function to inline the event handler for out input field

So use

```
function Product({product}) {...}
```

instead of

```
const Product = ({ product }) => {}
```